# Как закрыть Compose Dialog в accessibility mode?

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility

У меня есть дилог в compose

```
...
    Dialog(
        properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false),
        onDismissRequest = { eventReceiver.contentEventReceiver.onCellClick?.invoke(null) }
    ) {
        (LocalView.current.parent as DialogWindowProvider).window.apply {
            setDimAmount(0.8f)
            setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL)
        }

        rotator.ContentCellHorizontalRotator(
            selectedContent = selectedItem
        )
    }
...
```

Вопрос в том, что у этого диалога нет `X` кнопки куда юзер может нажать и закрыть его, подразумевается, что юзер нажимает за пределю диалога и он закрывается.

Но, проблема в accessibility mode (допустим для людей с проблемами зрения), то в этом случае tack back будет читать все в экрана в том числе и доступные опции, но опции закрыть диалог нет. Другими словами человек открывший диалог не может его закрыть.

В iOS допустим для закрытия диалога есть out of the box жест - двумя пальцами провести по экрану фигуру Z, но я не нашел, чтоб такое было в андроиде.

У кого какие идеи на этот счет?

Comment: Вернее нужно взять [это](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/09/detection-of-gesture.html) решение и потом заменить LinearLayout на RelativeLayout, а вместо TextView положить `androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView`, который и будет центром compose приложения. А дальше уже думать как доставить результат детекта до диалога - или через state передать или сделать Modifier, что подписывается и отписывается на какую нибудь реализацию event в MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге оказалось, что есть такой жест в виде фигры "обратной L (одним пальцем вниз и влево" как описано в этой статье - https://qbalsdon.github.io/accessibility,/testing,/talkback,/voiceover/2023/05/10/accessibility-cheatsheets.html

Так же можно на устройстве проверить перечень нативных жестов -

```
Settings -> Accessibility -> TalkBack -> Settings -> Customise gestures
```